# How are modes generated in a waveguide?

Tags: communication, electromagnetism, waveguide

Its related to my previous question [Modes in waveguides](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/78489/modes-in-waveguides) I have a doubt that how are different modes actually generated? I mean in Digital and Analog communication, we studied how we modulate the signal to shift its spectrum. At that point of time (Output of modulator) its only electrical signal right (Please correct me if I'm wrong)? How do we generate EM wave corresponding to this modulated signal? How do we make sure that EM wave is belonging to that specific mode which is desired? What goes on the channel is the EM wave, right or the electrical signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key point: when we talk about the modes of a waveguide, we are often using that as shorthand for the *propagating* modes of the waveguide. However, the waveguide also has other modes, called [*evanescent* modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evanescent_wave). The evanescent modes don't carry energy along the waveguide, they just die out exponentially along the z-direction. Which is why those aren't normally the modes we mean when we talk about the modes of the waveguides. However, the evanescent modes are important to answering your question.

Let's say we place a feed antenna into a rectangular waveguide:

[image]

If we drive the antenna from outside, it will produce certain E and H field patterns.

We can express these fields as a superposition of the modes of the waveguide, so long as we consider both the propagating and the evanescent modes. This tells us how much of the input energy couples to the propagating modes and how much to the evanescent modes. Whatever part of the signal energy that corresponds to the propagating modes will propagate along the waveguide. The energy coupled into the evanescent mode effectively bounces back and forth. Some of it gets absorbed by conductive losses in the walls of the waveguide. But a larger part of it probably gets re-coupled to the feed antenna and appears as a reflection back up the feed line to the signal source.

Comment: So basically we use an antenna for mode generation, is it? And then is single mode propagation desirable as in optical fiber?

Comment: AFAIK (I work in fiber optics, not microwave waveguides), singlemode is much preferable in waveguide, for the same reason. Different modes propagate at different velocities, so if you launch a signal in multiple modes there will be dispersion (spreading out in time) as it travels down the waveguide.

Comment: I just had that doubt because in waveguide, all the modes till the highest mode at which we desire the operation will exist na. So, in order to have single mode propagation we will need to operate in lowest possible TE10?

Comment: Its off the topic but which book would you recommend for optical communication and which are the important topics in it?

Comment: Yes, you have to operate in the lowest mode to have single-mode operation. On fiber optics, why not come ask in chat? (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering)